# Laravel Auth::user() has no code completion for User model functions

Tags: laravel, authentication, model, code-completion

I am using Laravel and PHPStorm.

The auto completion works for all models, just not for the 'User', when I call it with `Auth::user()`.

When I call the `Auth::user()` I get the right user object, but the return type of `Auth::user()` is `Authenticatable` and not `User`. So I get no code completion for my user object which is very anoying because I use it very often. I think the problem has something to do with the return type of `Auth::user()` because it is `Authenticatable` and not `User`.

In the `config/auth.php` I already set the model to `app/User::class`.

Can you tell me how to cast the return value to the User model?

In this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aewCh.png) you can see the behaviour.

Comment: Can you please provide the name of the editor, any configuration you have made for Laravel support for your editor and your IDE project?

Comment: where are u calling auth::user?? Note try to call it on homecontroller. If u get the user in return that means that you are proppably calling auth::user() on a 'createUser' method, where the user doesnt even exists.

Comment: @A.Kootstra I am using PHPStorm and I am using the default configuration.

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi I use it in a lot of places. In controllers, models and sometimes views. The user does exist. The problem is just the code completion for the user object

Comment: try call it on homecontroller to see what u get

Comment: it is the same in all controllers, also in homecontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add laravel-ide-helper package to your project - https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper.

The package generates a help file for the IDE with all the Facades and their functions.
It fixes the Facades auto-completion so `Auth::user()` is fixes too

Answer (score 3):

```
Auth::user()
```

Auth is an Alias from ServiceProviders array in config/app.php if you directly use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`
 you will get a nice completion in PHPstorm as well as Sublime but it depends on the IDE.

Comment: I am already using Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth, but there is no code completion for my user

Comment: User Properties are not going to completed. Your IDE doesnt know wht is the name of your column in your DATABASE `Auth::user()->name` is not going to completed

Comment: if you add in the comment above the class `@property $name` then you also have a auto completion for your proberties.

Comment: @mmanuel make sure you have a correct namespace and PSR settings in PHPstorm. If your code is not completing at all look for `composer` folder in your vendor folder delete composer folder and restart PHPstorm. after restart run `composer dump-autoload`  in terminal.

Comment: my completion is working everywhere it is just not working for my user when I call it with `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I'm still seeing the issue, in spite of using ide-helper.

In my Laravel app, Eloquent model `App\User` is set for "User Providers" in /config/auth.php:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

I just rebuilt the file `_ide_helper.php` by running:
`php artisan ide-helper:generate`
and this is what I see for Auth()::user()

```
     * Get the currently authenticated user.
     *
     * @return \App\User|null \\this is desired
     * @static 
     */ 
    public static function user()
    {
                    /** @var \Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard $instance */
                    return $instance->user();
    }
```

Looking in the `_ide_helper.php` file, I see this:

[image]

Which results in undesired type hinting:

[image]

[image]

The end result, is that even with using the ide-helper, I'm still seeing the completion problems described by the OP.

The solution presented here solved a lot of related problems (the ide-helper package is a godsend), but I still have the OP's problem and the provided answer does not help.